# Sending data with viewbag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I am working on a project. I need to get several data from database and send to view. I have already a list of data. And I also want to send my another datas via viewbag. I queried my related data from database.

ClassController.cs

```
public ActionResult ClassTeacherDetail(int id)
        {

            ViewBag.dgr = db.Teachers.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();


            var myList = (from t in db.Appointments
                     from d in t.WeekDays
                     where t.TeacherId == id
                     select new { DayName=d.Name, WHours=t.Hours }
                ).ToList();


            // Get the languages which can be learned by the teacher based on teacher id
            var query = from t in db.Teachers.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                        from l in t.Languages
                        select new
                        {
                            LangName = l.Name,
                        };
            var list = new List<Language>();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                list.Add(new Language()
                {
                    Name = item.LangName
                });
            }

            return View(list);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRLe4.png)

As you see, I got the working hours and days from separate tables. By the way, what is the type of myList? If I would send it to view, what will the model type be?

How can I pass the myList?

Comment: Instead of using `ViewBag` use the Model instead. You gain type safety in your view template code.

Comment: you assign the wrong list, to ``ViewBag``. you assign ``myList`` to ``ViewBag`` and in the view you try to get dada from ``teacherDayHours``

Comment: But I already have a model in view

Comment: will you post your full controller code?

Comment: @JerdineSabio I posted full controller

Comment: @AtakanTekoglu you want to pass 2 models at the same time; mylist and list? Or myList only?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Yes that is what I want. I want to pass 2 models at the same time. I will show these 2 tables in the view page. But I get confused coz myList has two different data fields which come from Appointment and WeekDay tables.

Comment: @AtakanTekoglu follow the steps on my answer, you need to make a view model that will contain both lists.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. I overcame my problem.

Comment: @JerdineSabio If you don't mind, may you check my new question please?

Comment: @AtakanTekoglu yes sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myList is a List of type `Anonymous object`, there's nothing wrong with that but it will be hard to keep track of. What we need to do is make a class/model for it THEN make a viewmodel that will contain both variables.

1. Make a model or view model for myList anonymous object, I used TeacherAppointment;

```
// if the property/data type doesn't match with your Appointments model, please change accordingly
public class TeacherAppointment {
   public string DayName {get;set;}
   public string WHours {get;set;}
}
```

2. Update myList LINQ to store it to a TeacherAppointment object. myList is now `List<TeacherAppointment>`

```
var myList = (from t in db.Appointments
                from d in t.WeekDays
                where t.TeacherId == id
                select new TeacherAppointment { DayName=d.Name, WHours=t.Hours }
              ).ToList();
```

3. Create a view model that will contain 2 models.

```
public class TeacherDetailViewModel{
   public List<TeacherAppointment> TeacherAppointments {get;set;}
   public List<Language> Languages {get;set;}
}
```

4. In your view, you should use;

```
@model TeacherDetailViewModel
```

5. Your controller code should be;

```
public ActionResult ClassTeacherDetail(int id)
        {

            ViewBag.dgr = db.Teachers.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();


            var myList = (from t in db.Appointments
                     from d in t.WeekDays
                     where t.TeacherId == id
                     select new TeacherAppointment { DayName=d.Name, WHours=t.Hours }
                ).ToList();


            // Get the languages which can be learned by the teacher based on teacher id
            var query = from t in db.Teachers.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                        from l in t.Languages
                        select new
                        {
                            LangName = l.Name,
                        };
            var list = new List<Language>();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                list.Add(new Language()
                {
                    Name = item.LangName
                });
            }

            // instantiate view model
            TeacherDetailViewModel tdvm = new TeacherDetailViewModel();

            // assign myList and list to TeacherDetailViewModel
            tdvm.TeacherAppointments = myList;
            tdvm.Languages = list;

            // Pass tdvm to the view
            return View(tdvm);
        }
```

6. In your view again, if you want to loop;

```
@foreach(var a in Model.TeacherAppointments){
   ...
}

@foreach(var b in Model.Languages){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. I overcame my problem.

Comment: @AtakanTekoglu you're welcome! Thanks too. Please accept this as the correct answer for completion.